# How can i remove a deleted row inside a table using Jquery for my asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

i have the following view:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#removerow").click(function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
</script>


<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>This Question Currently has @Model.Answers.Count() Answers/s. </legend>
<table id="incrementanswer">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
        <th>
            Answer 
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var answer in Model.Answers.OrderBy(a=> a.IsRight))
{
       <tr id =  "removerow">

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => answer.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => answer.Answer_Description.description)
        </td>
        <td>
         @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Answer",
        new { id = answer.AnswersID },
          new AjaxOptions
          {
              Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete this Answer ?",
              HttpMethod = "Post",
              UpdateTargetId = "toremove",
              OnSuccess = "removePartial2"
          })


        </td>
        </tr>
}
</table>
<div id = "progress2">
<img src= "@Url.Content("~/Content/images/ajax-loader1.gif") ">
</div>
```

which contains a script and an ajax.actionlink that calls this script after clicking on the delete link. Currently the row will be removed only if it is the first row in a table and also the row will be deleted before confirming the deletion ,, so what might be the problem ?

edited:- i have updated my view to the following, **but i still can not force the removePartial2 script to remove the row which was deleted:-**

```
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function removePartial2() {
        $(this).remove();
}
</script>

}

<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>This Question Currently has @Model.Answers.Count() Answers/s. </legend>
<table id="incrementanswer">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
        <th>
            Answer 
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var answer in Model.Answers.OrderBy(a=> a.IsRight))
{
       <tr id =  @answer.AnswersID>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => answer.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => answer.Answer_Description.description)
        </td>
        <td>
         @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Answer",
        new { id = answer.AnswersID },
          new AjaxOptions
          {
              Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete this Answer ?",
              HttpMethod = "Post",
              UpdateTargetId = @answer.AnswersID.ToString(),
              OnSuccess = "removePartial2"
          })


        </td>
        </tr>
}
</table>
<div id = "progress2">
<img src= "@Url.Content("~/Content/images/ajax-loader1.gif") ">
</div>
```

Comment: What is $(this) in your removePartial2? Are you sure that's referencing the object you want it to?

Comment: i am trying to force the application to remove the intended row ,, that why i am using $(this); but seems it is not working well......

Answer (score 0):

1. "Ids. Must. Be. Unique."
2. You have a function that removes the row if the ROW is clicked, not just the delete option. I would remove your first javascript block, and only use the ajax call function.
3. OnSuccess is whether or not the Ajax call returned a [200 code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onsuccess.aspx). This is only if the ajax call was successful - It's not checking to see if a returned value was correct.

Comment: @johnG I've updated my answer. If your ajax call is successful you delete the row. That means a 200 return code from the server.